# Sorting table doesnt working Vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I found this pen https://codepen.io/cfjedimaster/pen/BYpJgj But it doesn't work in my implementation. I can't understand what i am doing wrong

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr class="header">
      <th @click="sort('campaign')">Campaign</th> // click heandler
      <th @click="sort('time')">Time</th>
      <th @click="sort('views')">Views</th>
      <th @click="sort('visitors')">Visitors</th>
      <th @click="sort('ctr')">CTR</th>
      <th @click="sort('cpc')">CPC</th>
      <th @click="sort('cpv')">CPV</th>
      <th @click="sort('cpm')">CPM</th>
      <th @click="sort('status')">Status</th>
   </tr>
 </thead>
   <tbody> //target table
     <tr v-for="item in data" :key="item.id"> // loop
       <td>{{item.name}}</td> //row
       <td>{{item.time}}</td>
       <td>{{item.views}}</td>
       <td>{{item.visitors}}</td>
       <td>{{item.ctr}}</td>
       <td>{{item.cpc}}</td>
       <td>{{item.cpv}}</td>
       <td>{{item.cpm}}</td>
       <td>{{item.status}}</td>
     </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>

data(){
 return{
   data: [], // data
     currentSort:'campaign', // dynamic property
     currentSortDir:'asc'
   }
},
methods:{ // methods
  getData(){
    this.data = this.$store.state.graphArr // get data from store
  },
  sort(s) { // sort function
    //if s == current sort, reverse
    if(s === this.currentSort) { // if statement
      this.currentSortDir = this.currentSortDir==='asc'?'desc':'asc';                  }
      this.currentSort = s; // setting currentSortDir
    }
      },
computed:{ // computed
  sortedCats() { // where this function should be called
    return this.data.sort((a,b) => { // ES Lint highlits "this". Unexpetced side effect
      let modifier = 1;
      if(this.currentSortDir === 'desc') modifier = -1;
      if(a[this.currentSort] < b[this.currentSort]) return -1 * modifier;
      if(a[this.currentSort] > b[this.currentSort]) return 1 * modifier;
        return 0;
    });
  }
}
```

Maybe i should somewhere call sortedCats function? And the role of computed property at all in this case?

Comment: are you calling `getData()` anywhere?

Comment: Yes. On Creating

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to loop through `sortedCats` array to get the desired result instead of `data` as `sortedCats` returns new value every time sort is clicked through `computed` property.

```
<tr v-for="item in sortedCats" :key="item.id">
```